# Can an item that was imbued with the magic weapon spell become a pact weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, warlock

Can a warlock make a weapon that is imbued with *magic weapon* spell his/her pact weapon?

Example:
A sorcerer that has wizard levels extended the spell *magic weapon* for the duration to be 2 hours and cast it on the longsword becoming the longsword +1 and the warlock decided to make it his pact weapon. Will the warlock keep the longsword's magical properties after the duration of the spell *magic weapon*?